# Programmatically render the getters of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, figma, figma-api

I'm desperately looking to render this object programmatically, so I can work with it with handlebars.js, when I try to pass a property as it is of now, I do get an error about the fact that handlebars can process only "own" properties.
The object looks like this, I'm not able to use the (i guess getters?) properties with (...)

```
FrameNode {id: '555:42'}
id: "555:42"
absoluteBoundingBox: (...)
absoluteRenderBounds: (...)
absoluteTransform: (...)
attachedConnectors: (...)
backgroundStyleId: (...)
backgrounds: (...)
blendMode: (...)
bottomLeftRadius: (...)
bottomRightRadius: (...)
children: (...)
clipsContent: (...)
componentPropertyReferences: (...)
constrainProportions: (...)
constraints: (...)
cornerRadius: (...)
cornerSmoothing: (...)
counterAxisAlignItems: (...)
counterAxisSizingMode: (...)
dashPattern: (...)
```

Is it even possible to invoke these programmatically?

I tried really everything, but nothing seemed to work. It might just be my lack of knowledge though.

Comment: Have you tried ```JOSN.stringify(yourObject,null,2)``` ? This would render it.  You should be able to convert it to a standard object with ```newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject))``` ?

Comment: @user3094755 Hello, yes, it copies/renders just the id, the rest of the getters do not render/copy. Thanks for the input though!